# How to disable time from bootstrap-year-calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I try to hide the time from bootstrap year calendar but It doesn't work for me! I want just display date in the calendar then save this date !How can I desactivate the time in the calendar !
I have used

> displayEventTime: false
>
> showtime: false

But they doens't work !

Here is my code ! can any one help me please! thanks in advance

```
 <!-- Bootstrap Material Datetime Picker Css -->
 < link href = "../plugins/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css"
   rel = "stylesheet" / >
 <!-- Bootstrap Material Datetime Picker Css -->
 < link href = "../../plugins/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/css/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.css"
   rel = "stylesheet" / >
  <!-- Waves Effect Plugin Js -->
    < script src = "../plugins/calendar/bootstrap-year-calendar.js" > < /script>
    <!-- Waves Effect Plugin Js -->
   < script src = "../plugins/calendar/bootstrap-year-calendar.min.js" > < /script>
 <!-- Waves Effect Plugin Js -->

< script src = "../plugins/momentjs/moment.js" > < /script> < script src = "../plugins/momentjs/moment-range.js" > < /script> < script src = "../js/calendar.js" > < /script>
 <!-- Bootstrap Material Datetime Picker Plugin Js -->
  < script src = "../plugins/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-
   material-datetimepicker.js" > < /script>
 function runclalendar(tasksList) {

var dataset = [];
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
for (var i = 0; i < tasksList.length; i++) {
    var taskdei = tasksList[i].req;
    var eventss = {};
    eventss.i = i,
        eventss.name = taskdei.absenceReason,
        eventss.location = taskdei.absenceReasonlabel,
        eventss.startDate = moment(taskdei.startDate),
        eventss.endDate = moment(taskdei.endDate)
    dataset.push(eventss);
}
$('#calendar').calendar({
    enableContextMenu: true,
    enableRangeSelection: true,
    minView: 2,
    dateonly: true,
    displayEventTime: false,
    contextMenuItems: [{
        text: 'Update',
        click: editEvent
    }, {
        text: 'Delete',
        click: deleteEvent
    }],
    selectRange: function(e) {
        editEvent({
            startDate: e.startDate,
            endDate: e.endDate
        });
    },
    mouseOnDay: function(e) {
        if (e.events.length > 0) {
            var content = '';

            for (var i in e.events) {
                content += '<div class="event-tooltip-content">' +
                    '<div class="event-name" style="color:' + e.events[i].color + '"> Congé de type ' + e.events[i].location + ' ( ' + e.events[i].name + ' ) </div>' +
                    '<div class="event-location">du ' + moment(e.events[i].startDate).format("YYYY/MM/DD") + ' au ' + moment(e.events[i].endDate).format("YYYY/MM/DD") + '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
            }

            $(e.element).popover({
                trigger: 'manual',
                container: 'body',
                html: true,
                content: content
            });

            $(e.element).popover('show');
        }
    },
    mouseOutDay: function(e) {
        if (e.events.length > 0) {
            $(e.element).popover('hide');
        }
    },
    dayContextMenu: function(e) {
        $(e.element).popover('hide');
    },


    dataSource: dataset
});
console.log(dataset);
$('#save-event').click(function() {
    saveEvent();
});
 }
```

Comment: Provide link to plugin source

Comment: I have added them

Comment: Those are not links to any documentation. Can't assume people know where your plugin comes from. There are thousands of plugins around

Comment: Can you please share HTML with this also? It will be good if you can share a live example with [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)